# adding xml node from a file as a node of another document

Tags: c#, xml

I load an XML document:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("MyFile.xml");
```

And also create a new document:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocSettings = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode xmlDecl = xmlDocSettings.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, "", "");
xmlDocSettings.AppendChild(xmlDecl);
XmlElement root = xmlDocSettings.CreateElement("", "Test", "");
root.SetAttribute("TestAttribute", "AttributeValue");
xmlDocSettings.AppendChild(root);
```

Now I want to insert the content of `xmlDoc` to `xmlDocSettings`.  How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To copy content from one document to another, use `Document.importNode` ([W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode), [.NET implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx) docs).

```
xmlDocSettings.DocumentElement.AppendChild(
    xmlDocSettings.ImportNode(xmlDoc.DocumentElement, true)
);
```

Comment: Thanks,  I used your example, to add any node to any other node - I recommend changing the answer for the generic example: 
`XmlDocument targetDoc = nodeToWriteOn.OwnerDocument;
XmlNode nodeToAdd = targetDoc.ImportNode(node, true);
nodeToWriteOn.AppendChild(nodeToAdd);`